# iTextSharp, a popular PDF generation tool. Version 5.5.11 is FIPS compliant.

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

Can I know the list of iTextSharp versions and if they support FIPS compliance? From which version has iTextSharp started supporting FIPS compliance without using MD5 algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

iText (or more precisely, the BouncyCastle dependency) is FIPS compliant, but is not FIPS certified. This is independent from the iText version.

More information about BouncyCastle's FIPS compliance can be found on their website: https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips_faq.html

On a different note: iText 5 for .NET is no longer called iTextSharp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Another discussion where Paulo mentioned 'The MD5 need by the PDF is generated with the bouncy castle library and won't be affected by the compliance flag turned on' Is it true for iText versions above 5 only? I mean, are only versions 5 and above FIPS compliant?

Comment: Paulo, who was one of the core contributors for iText 2 and iText 5, probably knows this better than I do. Paulo also confirms that you should not be looking at iText, you should look at Bouncy Castle.